# Why does my CheckTypeRoomForGuest() methods not loop all guest and always true?

Tags: java

I have three class is Guest, Class and Fileprocessing. I have to choose RoomType appropriate and the room with the smallest value. For example Guest A [NOR,VIP] want to book a room type is NOR, if we no longer room type NOR they will choose VIP room.

in class Room:

```
public class Room {
    private String roomName;
    private String roomType;
    private int roomNumSeat;
    private int status;
    }
```

in class Guest:

```
public class Guest {
    private String guestID;
    private String guestName;
    private double time;
    private int guestNum;
    private double bonus;
    private ArrayList<String> guestServices= new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> guestRoomType= new ArrayList<String>();
    private Room room;
    private Services services;

}
```

in class Fileprocessing:

```
public class Fileprocessing {

    List<Room> resultInit = new ArrayList<Room>();
    //List<Services> resultInit1 = new ArrayList<Services>();
    List<Guest> resultThue = new ArrayList<Guest>();
    List<TenantInformation> resultttkt= new ArrayList<TenantInformation>();


    public Fileprocessing(){}


public boolean CheckTypeRoomForGuest() {
        for (Guest g: this.resultThue) {
            for (Room r : this.resultInit) {
                for (String s : g.getGuestRoomType()) {
                    if (s.equals(r.getRoomType())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<TenantInformation> roomforGuest() {
        for (Guest g: this.resultThue){
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            Room selectedRoom = null;
            TenantInformation tt = new TenantInformation();
            for (Room r: this.resultInit) {
                if((g.getGuestNum()-k.getRoomSeat() < min)&& (CheckTypeRoomForGuest())&& (r.getRoomStatus==0)) {
                    min = Math.abs(g.getGuestNum() - r.getRoomSeat());
                    selectedRoom = r;
                }
            }

            tt.setGuestName(g.getGuestName());
            tt.setRoomName(selectedRoom.getRoomName());
            r.setRoomStatus(Room.ROOM_OCCUPIED);
            resultttkt.add(tt);
        }
    }
```

Why does my CheckTypeRoomForGuest() menthods not loop all guest and always true?

Comment: You're missing some kind of variable in your enhanced for loop - I will assume you meant to put a "g" there.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what this method is saying:

```
public boolean CheckTypeRoomForGuest() {
    for (Guest g: this.resultThue) {
        for (Room r : this.resultInit) {
            for (String s : k.getGuestRoomType()) {
                if (s.equals(r.getRoomType())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

It says:

- For *each* guest in the collection/iterable `this.resultThue`:

  - For *each* room in the collection/iterable `this.resultInit` referenced by r:

    - For *each* String contained in `k.getGuestRoomType()` referenced by s:

      - If `s` matches the same as `r`'s room type:

        - We return to where we were called with a value of `true`.

If *any* value in `k.getGuestRoomType()` matches any result within that iterable, it will return `true`.  That's why, in a nut shell, you're returning true.

If you weren't looping at all, you would be getting false back instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mistakes in translated into English